# Error occurred in the output of insertion and deletion operation with an array in data structure

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I am a newbie to data structure I have done the following code for `Insertion` and `Deletion` operation with an array, it runs without error but there is a runtime error plz help me to find out the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5


    void insert(int *,int pos, int num);
    void del(int *,int pos);
    void display(int *);


        int main()
        {

            int arr[5];



            /*Start of array insertion function*/
                insert(arr,1,11);
                insert(arr,2,12);
                insert(arr,3,13);
                insert(arr,4,14);
                insert(arr,5,15);
            /*End of array insertion function*/

            printf("Elements of Array:\n"); /*printing aray elements after insertion*/
                display(arr); /*display funtion called for printing array elements*/

            /*Start of deletion of array function*/
                del(arr,5);
                del(arr,2);
            /*End of deletion of array function*/

            printf("After deletion of array:\n");/*printing array elements after deletion*/
                display(arr);/*display function called for printing array element*/




            return 0;

        }

        /*inserts an element num at given position pos*/
            void insert(int *arr, int pos, int num) {

            /*shifts element to right*/
                int i;
                    for (i = MAX - 1; i >= pos; i--) {
                /*swapping*/
                    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
                    arr[i]=num;
                 }

        }

        /*deletes an element from the given position pos */
            void del(int *arr, int pos){
            /*skip to the desired position*/
                int i;
                    for(i=pos;i<MAX;i++){
                        arr[i-1]=arr[i];
                        arr[i-1]=0;

                }

        }

        /*display the content of the array*/
            void display(int *arr){
            /*traverse the entire array*/
            int i;
                for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
                    printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
                    printf("\n");

                }
        }
```

The following output is showing-

```
Elements of Array:
-13136  
11  
12  
13  
14  
After deletion of array:
-13136  
0   
0   
0   
14  

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But my expected output is-

```
Elements of Array:

11 12 13 14 15

After deletion:

11 0 13 14 0
```

What's the problem with my code why the wrong output showing for `Insertion` and `Deletion`operation?

Comment: I think you need to pay attention to a couple of elements:
1) decide if you want to use 0 or 1 as starting element of an array, and pay attention to that choice: it's really easier to use 0, since the compiler do so.
2)Check if `pos ` is a valid position for the array. For example you can't insert an element at position 9 or -2

Comment: The main error is that you are assigning a value at every step of the for in the "del" function. Also you don't need a for, just go for the `pos - 1` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had some spare time: As I said in the comment, the main error is the assignment of variable arr[] element at every step of the for. You just need to set it once. Also you don't even need a for in the delete function:

```
#define MAX 5

void insert(int *,int pos, int num);
void del(int *,int pos);
void display(int *);

int main()
{
    int arr[MAX];

    /*Start of array insertion function*/
        insert(arr,1,11);
        insert(arr,2,12);
        insert(arr,3,13);
        insert(arr,4,14);
        insert(arr,5,15);
    /*End of array insertion function*/

    printf("Elements of Array:\n"); /*printing aray elements after insertion*/
        display(arr); /*display funtion called for printing array elements*/

    /*Start of deletion of array function*/
        del(arr,5);
        del(arr,2);
    /*End of deletion of array function*/

    printf("After deletion of array:\n");/*printing array elements after deletion*/
        display(arr);/*display function called for printing array element*/




    return 0;

}

/*inserts an element num at given position pos*/
void insert(int *arr, int pos, int num) {

    if(pos < 1 || pos > MAX)
    {
        printf("INSERT: Invalid position %d\n",pos);
        return;
    }

    /*shifts element to right*/
    int i;
    for (i = MAX - 1; i > pos ; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[pos - 1] = num;

}

/*deletes an element from the given position pos */
void del(int *arr, int pos){

    if(pos < 1 || pos > MAX)
    {
        printf("DELETE: Invalid position %d\n",pos);
        return;
    }

    arr[pos - 1]=0;
}

/*display the content of the array*/
    void display(int *arr){
    /*traverse the entire array*/
    int i;
        for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
            printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
            printf("\n");

        }
}
```

I also used MAX to set the array size, so to avoid errors and added a check to insert and delete, to be sure pos is a valid position

Comment: what will be the problem if I used arr[i]= num instead of arr[pos - 1] = num; in insertion operation

Comment: In the insert function sounds like a useless operation... The problem was in the delete function, where every array element you passed in was set to 0

Comment: and what is the function of this line "int i;
    for (i = MAX - 1; i > pos ; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }" in the insertion operation because only "   arr[pos - 1] = num;" this line can complete the insertion operation

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question:

`arr[i] = arr[i-1] ` move the value to the next array position

`arr[pos - 1]` assign the value to the requested position

Comment: only "  arr[pos - 1] = num;" this is working there is no need to assign a loop in the insertion operation